# What is a ContentResolver requestSync Account name?

Tags: android, synchronization, accountmanager

I'm trying to call ContentResolver.requestSync.  It says in the docs I need 3 parameters.  The first is an Account which states:

which account should be synced

There are 2 Account constructors.  Unless there is some other way to get an Account, I assume I would want the:

public Account(String name, String type)

There is nothing in the documentation for this constructor.

While I see I need a name and a type, I don't know what Strings I would use.

I looked in the SampleSyncAdapter sample from Google and the only place I can find that does this is in AuthenticatorActivity:

final Account account = new Account(mUsername, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);

However, my code doesn't have a user login, so what "name" would I use?

How do I create an Account object?

Answer (score 2):

```
AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
String EmailID=null
for (Account account : list) 
    if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) 
            EmailID=account.name;
             .
             .
             .
             .
```

This code can be used to get the account details.